# Html Navbar menu for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

My navbar is not working the way i want, when i resize my browser to a mobile screen-size and click the button to make the links appear, the links appear on the right side of the logo. I've looked on many websites but never found an answer.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Timmage</title>
        <meta charset="Utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img class="logga" src="images/Timmage.png" alt="logga"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href = "#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Menu<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href = "#">Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Uploads</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Setting</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Log out</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1>Welcome to Timmage!</h1>
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where do you want them to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your logo and the toggle in a div with a class of `.navbar-header`

See the plnkr - https://plnkr.co/edit/sb7vJ5mMDMpO2VMPmelL?p=preview

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
    <img class="logga" src="images/Timmage.png" alt="logga" />
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>    
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu                                                                <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Uploads</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Setting</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Log out</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">My Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now my website looks kind of what it should, my links are now below my logo in the navbar when in desktop mode :-(

Comment: @MarcusLönnqvist my bad! I've updated the answer now, hope this helps and works this time!

Comment: That was great, thank you for your help, it works now!